# Regex Capture mutiple repeating pattern Pattern

Tags: regex

I have a question on parsing multiple repeating group using regex.
A user might enter some query, which i need to parse and construct the correct sql statement out of it.
Someone might enter:

```
Artist:Rolling Stones
Artist:"Rolling Stones"
Artist:"Rolling Stones" AND Title:Satisfaction
Artist:"Rolling Stones" AND Title:Satisfaction AND FileType:mp3
```

This regex would parse the first 2 samples:

```
(([A-Za-z].+?):("?.+"?)\s(AND|and|Or|or)?)
```

But i could have 1,2 or n of the same group. Is there something, where i could say repeat that multiple times and use the same pattern to match also the Title in sample 3 and Title and FileType in sample 4.

I came up with this:

```
(([A-Za-z].+?):("?.+"?)\s(AND|and|Or|or)?)\s+?(([A-Za-z].+?):("?.+"?)(AND|and|Or|or)?)?
```

That would capture sample 3, but does not match on 1 and 2.

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: What is the tool or language? This `Artist:Rolling Stones` and `Artist:"Rolling Stones"` can occur both between double quotes and without? what if OR or AND are part of the title?

Comment: Seems to me that regex is not the best tool for this. I would suggest using something like [antler](https://www.antlr.org/) to define syntax for your queries and translate them further into SQL

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Will try it.. the language i am using is c#. Might end up doing maybe some string manipulations like split, index, substring and then use regex on those to parse further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if regex is the best tool for the job, but I came up with

```
(\w+?\:\"?.+?\"?(?=(\sAND|\sOR|$)))
```

You can see it matches your tokens,
Explanation: it uses positive lookahead to ensure every token has after AND OR or a line termination, so your 1st and 3rd match

In your fist group you will find your query and in the second group you will find the ANDs and ORs

[image]
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1F10Ry/1)

Explanation: uses lookahead to find the words AND or OR to delimit the tokens, also considering end of line to match single tokens

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daniel. This helps alot.
Only problem is, if i have an AND or OR inside the the Artist or Title, but i can handle that. This needs then be escaped like "\AND" etc.